# Group elements of the data set if they are next to each other with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a data set (ex. 1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7) and I want to group items of the same value but only if they are next to each other minimum 3 times.

Is there a way?
I've tried using combinations of Count and GroupBy and Select in every way I know but I can't find a right one.

Or if it can't be done with LINQ then maybe some other way?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Output: 2,2,2,6,6,6

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd strive for a 100% LINQ solution for this:

```
var r = new List<List<int>>() { new () { source.First() } };

foreach(var e in source.Skip(1)){
  if(e == r.Last().Last()) r.Last().Add(e);
  else r.Add(new(){ e });
}

return r.Where(l => l.Count > 2);
```

<sup>The `.Last()` calls can be replaced with `[^1]` if you like</sup>

This works like:

- have an output that is a list of lists
- put the first item in the input, into the output
- For the second input items onward, if the input item is the same as the **last int** in the output, add the input item to the **last list** in the output,
- Otherwise make a new list containing the input int and add it onto the end of the output lists
- Keep only those output lists longer than 2

If he output is like:

```
[
  [2,2,2],
  [6,6,6]
]
```

Aggregate can be pushed into doing the same thing; this is simply an accumulator (`r`), an iteration (`foreach`) and an op on the result `Where`

```
var result = source.Skip(1).Aggregate(
    new List<List<int>>() { new List<int> { source.First() } }, 
    (r,e) => {
      if(e == r.Last().Last()) r.Last().Add(e);
      else r.Add(new List<int>(){ e });
      return r;
    },
    r => r.Where(l => l.Count > 2)
);
```

..but would you want to be the one to explain it to the new dev?

---

Another LINQy way would be to establish a counter that incremented by one each time the value in the source array changes compared to the pervious version, then group by this integer, and return only those groups 3+, but I don't like this so much because it's a bit "WTF"

```
var source = new[]{1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7};
int ctr = 0;
var result = source.Select(
  (e,i) => new[]{ i==0 || e != source[i-1] ? ++ctr : ctr, e}
)
.GroupBy(
  arr => arr[0], 
  arr => arr[1]
)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 2);
```

Comment: If you want the result as a single array, call `.SelectMany(x => x)`  on the result of the Where in the first one, or the Aggregate in the second

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the [`GroupAdjacent`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent.htm) or the [`RunLengthEncode`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_RunLengthEncode.htm) operators, from the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) package. The former groups adjacent elements in the sequence, that have the same key. The key is retrieved by invoking a `keySelector` lambda parameter. The later compares the adjacent elements, and emits a single `KeyValuePair<T, int>` for each series of equal elements. The `int` value of the `KeyValuePair<T, int>` represents the number of consecutive equal elements. Example:

```
var source = new[] { 1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7 };

IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, int>> grouped = MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable
    .GroupAdjacent(source, x => x);
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {group.Key}, Elements: {String.Join(", ", group)}");
}
Console.WriteLine();

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> pairs = MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable
    .RunLengthEncode(source);
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {pair.Key}, Value: {pair.Value}");
}
```

Output:

```
Key: 1, Elements: 1, 1
Key: 4, Elements: 4
Key: 6, Elements: 6
Key: 3, Elements: 3, 3
Key: 1, Elements: 1
Key: 2, Elements: 2, 2, 2
Key: 6, Elements: 6, 6, 6
Key: 7, Elements: 7

Key: 1, Value: 2
Key: 4, Value: 1
Key: 6, Value: 1
Key: 3, Value: 2
Key: 1, Value: 1
Key: 2, Value: 3
Key: 6, Value: 3
Key: 7, Value: 1
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mZtfwO).

In the above example I've used the operators as normal methods, because I am not a fan of adding `using MoreLinq;` and "polluting" the IntelliSense of the Visual Studio with all the specialized operators of the MoreLinq package. An alternative is to enable each operator selectively like this:

```
using static MoreLinq.Extensions.GroupAdjacentExtension;
using static MoreLinq.Extensions.RunLengthEncodeExtension;
```

If you don't like the idea of adding a dependency on a third-party package, you could grab the source code of these operators ([1](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs), [2](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/RunLengthEncode.cs)), and embed it directly into your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're nostalgic and like stuff like the Obfuscated C code contest, you could solve it like this.
(No best practice claims included)

```
        int[] n = {1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7};
        var t = new int [n.Length][];
        for (var i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
            t[i] = new []{n[i], i == 0 ? 0 : n[i] == n[i - 1] ? t[i - 1][1] : t[i - 1][1] + 1};

        var r = t.GroupBy(x => x[1], x => x[0])
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 2)
                 .SelectMany(g => g);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", r));
```

In the end Linq is likely not the best solution here.
A simple for-loop with 1,2,3 additional loop-variables to track the "group index" and the last value makes likely more sense.
Even if it's 2 lines more code written.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Linq just to use Linq.

I'd rather suggest using a simple **for loop** to loop over your `input` array and populate the `output` list. To keep track of which number is currently being repeated (if any), I'd use a variable (`repeatedNumber`) that's initially set to `null`.

In this approach, a number can only be assigned to `repeatedNumber` if it fulfills the *minimum requirement of repeated items*. Hence, for your example input, `repeatedNumber` would start at `null`, then eventually be set to `2`, then be set to `6`, and then be reset to `null`.

One perhaps good use of Linq here is to check if the *minimum requirement of repeated items* is fulfilled for a given item in `input`, by checking the necessary consecutive items in `input`:

```
input
    .Skip(items up to and including current item)
    .Take(minimum requirement of repeated items - 1)
    .All(equal to current item)
```

I'll name this *minimum requirement of repeated items* `repetitionRequirement`. (In your question post, `repetitionRequirement` is `3`.)

The logic in the **for loop** goes a follows:

- `number = input[i]`
- **If `number` is equal to `repeatedNumber`**, it means that the previously repeated item continues being repeated

  - Add `number` to `output`
- **Otherwise, if the *minimum requirement of repeated items* is fulfilled for `number`** (i.e. if the `repetitionRequirement - 1` items directly following `number` in `input` are all equal to `number`), it means that `number` is the first instance of a new repeated item

  - Set `repeatedNumber` equal to `number`
  - Add `number` to `output`
- **Otherwise, if `repeatedNumber` has value**, it means that the previously repeated item just ended its repetition

  - Set `repeatedNumber` to `null`

Here is a suggested implementation:
*(I'd suggest finding a more descriptive method name)*

```csharp
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;

public static List<int> GetOutput(int[] input, int repetitionRequirement)
{
    var consecutiveCount = repetitionRequirement - 1;
    
    var output = new List<int>();
    
    int? repeatedNumber = null;
            
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        var number = input[i];
        
        if (number == repeatedNumber)
        {
            output.Add(number);
        }
        else if (i + consecutiveCount < input.Length &&
            input.Skip(i + 1).Take(consecutiveCount).All(num => num == number))
        {
            repeatedNumber = number;
            output.Add(number);
        }
        else if (repeatedNumber.HasValue)
        {
            repeatedNumber = null;
        }
    }
    
    return output;
}
```

By calling it with your example input:

```csharp
var dataSet = new[] { 1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7 };

var output = GetOutput(dataSet, 3);
```

you get the following output:

> { 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6 }

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DaDYoX).